# Find a matrix $A$ such that $u$ is in $\operatorname{Null}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I tried to solve this problem in the following way, I just need you to tell me if it's right.

> Find a matrix $A$ such that $u$ is in $\operatorname{Null}(A)$.
>   $$u = \begin{bmatrix}
>        2 \\ 1 \\ 2
>      \end{bmatrix}$$

I found $A$ in the following way:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
       a&\frac{1}{2}u&u  
     \end{bmatrix}$$
where $a = \begin{bmatrix}
       -2 \\ -3 \\ 3
     \end{bmatrix}$
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
       -2&1&2 \\ -3&1/2&1 \\ 3&1&2
     \end{bmatrix}$$
If I reduce it to reduced row echelon form, $\dim(\operatorname{Null}(A))=1$. Is this the correct solution?

Comment: Did you check that $Au=0$? It doesn't seem to be. [The snarky answer to this problem, as written, is $A = 0$, but maybe you want $u$ to span the null space.]

Comment: You can check whether your solution is correct, since $u \in Null(A)$ if and only if $Au = 0$.  Does $Au = 0$ for your choice of $A$?  Also, since the problem doesn't specify you need to use a $3$-by-$3$ matrix, did you consider trying the smallest possible size for $A$?  It's always a good practice to seek the simplest examples possible.  Does $A$ have to have $3$ rows?  Does $A$ have to have $3$ columns?

Comment: Is $A=0$ allowed? :-)

Comment: @MichaelJoyce I thought that for $u$ to be in $Null(A)$, $u$ has to be in $A$ and not to be an independent vector. So, my solution wasn't correct.

Comment: @DylanMoreland I don't know what I want (joking), that's what the problem says. "Find $A$ such that $Null(A)$ contains the vector $u$(listed above)." If you guys, who are more proficient mathematicians don't get it, I don't either.

Comment: @Andrew: It seems like you might be confusing $Null(A)$ (the null space of $A$) with $Col(A)$ (the column space of $A$).

Comment: $u$ doesn't have to appear anywhere in the matrix $A$.  All you need is some matrix $A$ for which $Au = 0$.  The matrix $A$ you chose above doesn't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check your solution, you'll see that $A{\bf u}$ is not the zero vector; so, your solution does not work (and would have been happenstance if it did).

What you could use is that if $A{\bf u}=\bf0$, then the linear combination of the columns of $A$ given by the coordinates of $\bf u$ is zero.  That is you know, with ${\bf u}=\Bigl[{ \raise1pt\scriptscriptstyle 2\atop{\raise1pt 1  \atop  2}}\Bigr]$, that

$$\tag{1}
2A_1+A_2+2A_3=\bf0,
$$
where $A_i$ is the $i^{\rm th}$ column of $A$.

Any matrix $A$ with the appropriate dimensions which satisfies $(1)$ will work. So, just write down a, say, $3\times3$ matrix whose second column is the  $-{ 2}$ times the sum of   the first and  third columns.

Comment: $\frac{-1}{2}$? Isn't it $-2$ times the sum?

Comment: @Andrew eek... Yes, thank you.